# HTML5 programming questions

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have some questions:
1. why to choose PHP/ASP.NET over client side programming?
2. Can I call typescript code from javascript code?
3. Can I use TypeScript with angular?
4. I Angular is the next think in client side programming?
thanks

Comment: Your question is *much to broad*, and is more *opinion-based* than about an actual programming problem. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why to choose PHP/ASP.NET over client side programming

Server side rendering vs. client side rendering. Server side: great for SEO + static content. Client side: great for dynamic interactive apps. The lines are blurry however.

> Can I call typescript code from javascript code?

Yes. TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript and can be used from JavaScript.

> Can I use TypeScript with angular?

Yes : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-6vT7xgE4Y&hd=1

> I Angular is the next think in client side programming?

SPA frameworks are in general. Angular is the most popular SPA framework at the moment. Others are React, KnockoutJS, Durandal, BackboneJS, EmberJS. Also these can be mixed and matched (i.e. used alongside each other)

Comment: If I need to build a site with more then 200 views that need to be injected to the screen,Will Angular and it's siblings can handle the robustness I need?

Comment: Angular alone would be more than sufficient

Comment: thanks for your reply.one more issue, I have in the server side, web services that bringing to me a very large dtos.It's very dificult to handle it without tpesafety.how can I handle it ?